# Why does WordPress keep directing or forcing my pagination?

Tags: pagination

Why does WordPress keep directing or forcing my pagination?

I want my news pagination to work like this:

```
/news/?paged=2
```

But WordPress keeps forcing it to:

```
/news/page/2/
```

And then I get a 404 page!

**This only happens when the site is on a domain name, e.g https://hello-sample.com. But no issue on an IP with a port, e.g http://122.333.444.444:8000.** Why!??

Below is my news custom type:

```
function news_init() {
    $args = [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('News (Pages)'),
            'singular_name' => __('News'),
            'all_items' => 'All News'
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'news',
            'with_front' => true
        ],
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-star-filled',
        'supports' => [
            'title',
            'editor',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
        ],

    ];
    register_post_type('news', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'news_init');
```

Below is my news page template:

```
<?php
// tmp-news.php
/*
Template Name: News
Template Post Type: page
*/
get_header(); ?>
...
...

<?php
$featured_items = carbon_get_the_post_meta('featured');
$featured_item = reset($featured_items);
$featured_post = get_post($featured_item['id']);
if ($featured_post) {
    ....
}
?> 
...
...

<?php
// http://localhost:4000/news/?paged=2
$paged = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'];
$page_number = is_numeric($paged) && $paged > 0 ? $paged : 1;
$parent_slug = 'news';

$query_args = [
  'post_type' => $parent_slug,
  'post_status' => ['publish'],
  'posts_per_page' => 6, // limit posts.
  'post__not_in' => [$featured_items ? $featured_item['id'] : null],
  'paged' => $page_number,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC'
];

$the_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
$max_pages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
$next = (int)$max_pages === 0 || (int)$page_number === (int)$max_pages ? null :  ($page_number + 1);
$prev = (int)$page_number === 1 ? null : ($page_number - 1);
?>

<?php if (have_posts()): ?>

<!-- block: news items -->
<div class="bg-white" id="explore" style="scroll-margin-top: 80px;">

  <div class="container mx-auto py-20">

    <!-- block -->
    <div class="flex-center-x w-full px-1.5">

      <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

      <?php
      $post_date_format = carbon_get_the_post_meta('date') === 'mm_yy' ? 'F Y' : 'F j, Y';
      $post_excerpt = carbon_get_the_post_meta('excerpt');
      $post_thumbnail_link = carbon_get_the_post_meta('thumbnail_link');
      // $post_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($featured_item['id']);
      ?>

      <!-- item -->
      <div class="w-4/12 <lg:w-1/2 <md:w-full px-4.5 <md:px-2.5 pb-10">

        <div class="relative">
          <div class="aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
              class="bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat hover:opacity-60 transition-opacity duration-500"
              :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>)' }"
            >
            </a>
          </div>

          <span class="absolute bg-white top-0 py-2 px-3">
            <?php the_time($post_date_format); ?>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="py-4">
          <h3 class="text-2xl text-green-dark font-semibold">
            <a 
              href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
              class="hover:opacity-60 transition-opacity duration-500"
            >
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
          </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="text-xl">
          <?php echo $post_excerpt; ?>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- item -->

      <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
    <!-- block -->

  </div>

</div>
<!-- block -->

<?php if ($next || $prev): ?>

<!-- block: pager -->
<div class="bg-white">

  <!-- container: pager -->
  <div class="container mx-auto pb-20">

    <div class="flex-center-xy w-full px-1.5">
      <div class="w-full px-2.5 space-y-15 divide-y divide-red-theme">

        <!-- block -->
        <div class="flex">

          <!-- item -->
          <div class="w-4/12 px-2.5">

            <?php if ($prev): ?>
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu simple">
                <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/<?php echo $parent_slug; ?>/?paged=<?php echo $prev; ?>&#explore"
                    class="text-5xl hover:text-<?php echo $season; ?>-medium"
                  >
                    <i class="icon-chevron-thin-left"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <?php endif; ?>

          </div>
          <!-- item -->

          <!-- item -->
          <div class="w-4/12 px-2.5 flex-center-xy">
            <span><?php echo $page_number; ?> / <?php echo $max_pages; ?></span>
          </div>
          <!-- item -->

          <!-- item -->
          <div class="w-4/12 px-2.5">

            <?php if ($next): ?>
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu simple">
                <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/<?php echo $parent_slug; ?>/?paged=<?php echo $next; ?>&#explore"
                    class="text-5xl hover:text-<?php echo $season; ?>-medium float-right"
                  >
                    <i class="icon-chevron-thin-right"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <?php endif; ?>

          </div>
          <!-- item -->

        </div>
        <!-- block -->

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- container -->

</div>
<!-- block -->

<?php endif; ?>

<?php
// Reset Query
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas what I have missed?

**Edit:**

I have to add the following line to stop WordPress from forcing the URL (probably not a good idea?):

```
// functions.php
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

My Apache configuration for the domain name and IP address is as simple as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot "/home/.../hello-sample.com/"

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.hello-sample.com
       ServerAlias hello-sample.com

       DocumentRoot "/home/.../hello-sample.com/"

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: this is how pagination permalinks are supposed to work, and your preferred method may actually be worse for SEO and site performance. However, I notice your template is using the dreaded `query_posts` call, and to make things even worse you're then immediatley throwing away the result and using a 3rd custom `WP_Query` loop so the performance slowdown isn't just doubled, it's tripled!

Comment: Note that you can eliminate all your slowdowns and the additional code, and the pagination hacks by using `pre_get_posts` to modify the arguments, instead of creating additional brand new queries via `query_posts` and `WP_Query`. This also fixes several bugs you're unaware of when the pagination of your additional queries has more pages than the original query leading to 404's

Comment: @TomJNowell The WordPress main query is better left unchanged. So leave `pre_get_posts` out in a large project. For scalability, it is better to run a separate query to load different information with `WP_Query`. You can read this article https://www.billerickson.net/customize-the-wordpress-query/.

Comment: that is not true, I worked at WordPress.com VIP enterprise hosting reviewing peoples code so that it could scale to billions of pageviews per month, and what you've just told me not to do would have gotten your code blocked from deployment. Using `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query simply modifies the main query, but what you've done is to discard and create new additional queries that have extra cost and reduce scalability. You have not customized the query, you have created new second and third additional queries that have their own extra cost/weight

Comment: the reason you would want to use a separate query is because you're showing additional content, e.g. a sub-section, but you aren't using the main querys posts here so that doesn't apply. You use separate querys in addition to the main query, not instead of it. And you would never under any circumstances do it using `query_posts`, which does not override the default query, it discards it and starts a _new_ main query

Comment: @TomJNowell what if you have the main query reserved for blog and news posts are another custom post that you need to display on a separate template? what would you do then??

Comment: in addition to the posts in the main query, or instead of the posts in the main query? If it's in _addition_ to the posts in the main query, e.g. you need to show both, then a `WP_Query` would be the answer. If it's instead of the main query then `pre_get_posts` is still the answer. What I see in your question is the latter. The goal of `pre_get_posts` is to modify the parameters _before_ it goes to the database so you don't have the cost of making additional queries to get what you want, as well as the various issues it can cause

Comment: This is very helpful discussion, as I recently had to decide whether to use pre_get_posts or a new query.

Comment: @TomJNowell how do we use `pre_get_posts` to query a custom post type on a template then if `WP_Query` shouldn't be used??

Comment: your question made no mention of page templates until 31 minutes ago when you edited it, it was assumed from what you said that this was a standard post type archive, aka `archive-news.php`. This has ***massive*** consequences for both querying as well as your original question about pagination permalinks. I am glad to see `query_posts` has disappeared though. I wish you had shared this originally, it would have saved a lot of time and discussion

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's rewriting `?paged=2` to `/page/2` is because you're using a page template on a page, and pages support paginated content. You can insert read more page breaks and have multiple pages of content. Because of this, WordPress has pretty permalinks for that pagination.

It has nothing to do with wether your site uses an IP or a pretty TLD, it's likely you haven't got the same Nginx/Apache configuration and permalink settings between the sites.

There are 3 paths forward:

1. use an actual news archive post type and `archive-news.php`, WP already has a rewrite rule set up for it at the same URL that would display `index.php` or `archive.php`, and it would allow you to skip figuring out which page and page template and use `pre_get_posts`. You may even see improved tags in the header. I suspect you avoided this either out of habit or so you could use an options framework ( I spotted carbon )
2. Embrace it! `$paged = $wp_query->query_vars['paged']; should automatically pick up the variable, but it's actually easier and simpler to do` get_query_var( 'paged' )`
3. Use something other than `paged` as the URL parameter and change it to `$_GET['whatever the new name is']`.

Note that if you get what you wanted, the canonical URL for all pages will be identical.

### A sidenote on `__not_in` type parameters

As a sidenote, `'post__not_in' => [$featured_items ? $featured_item['id'] : null],` is easily the most expensive thing in your template. `__not_in` style parameters get more expensive as your tables grow in size. This is because the database doesn't skip those items, it copies the entire table into memory minus the items you didn't want, then runs the query on that new temporary table, which then gets discarded. This makes it very resource intensive.

Oddly enough, the inverse is much faster. This is why it's fast to ask for all posts that have the "show on homepage" option checked, but it's much much slower to ask for all posts that do not have "hide on homepage" checked. On a large site, flagging every post with "not featured" by default and loading that can be hundreds of times better for your server, even if there is only a single featured post.

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer and thoughts. It might be caused by the Apache configuration. But I don't know. See my edit above. I have some info saved on the News single page with Carbon Fields. And I need to pass that info to the query, that's why I think it is easier to use a page template, rather than using `archive-news.php`. I need to display the featured news on the News page, followed by the other news posts, that's why I think `WP_Query` is the better answer.

Comment: note that they are 3 paths forward, not 1 path with 3 steps, it's a multiple choice thing